# Changing the color of the Span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am a beginner in learning Jquery.
I tried a simple sign up form in jquery. 
here,if the username and password is not entered in the text box then a label is displayed with span saying"Please fill the username".
How to change the span font color? 
Here is my code:

```
if(user=="") { 
 $('#dis').slideDown().html("<span>Please type Username</span>");
 return false; 
}
```

Thank you...

Comment: Thats all your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just apply `color` in your span.

```
if(user=="") { 
  $('#dis').slideDown().html("<span style='color:green'>Please type Username</span>");
  return false; 
}
```

Or you can apply some class, then add the style into that.

```
if(user=="") { 
  $('#dis').slideDown().html("<span class='colorspan'>Please type Username</span>");
  return false; 
} 

.colorspan
 {
   color:green;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you and and it is not working in this case...   $('#dis').slideDown().html('<span id="error" style='color:green'>Please type Password</span>');

Comment: which case? can you post it in jsfiddle?

Comment: try like this $('#dis').slideDown().html("<span id='error' style='color:green'>Please type Password</span>");